# What would constitute an O(n^2 log n) algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, runtime

I am a beginner and am learning about O notation and runtime.

I am unsure of what an O(n^2 log n) algorithm would look like. For example, I believe that the merge sort algorithm is O(n log n), but if I were to use this to, for example, merge sort a 2d array: first looping through the rows and columns using a nested loop and appending those to a new list to make a single list and then using a merge sort algorithm on this list, would that be O(n^2 log n)?

Thanks,

Comment: Your algorithm would not be O(n^2 log n); you're starting with k^2 elements, where k is the size of the array.  The n you would be using in O() notation is k^2, because you measure the algorithm time to the *size* of the input, not some random parameter.  In terms of n, you're still O(n log n).

Comment: Thanks, so what would make an algorithm O(n^2 log n)?

Comment: Okay.  After writing what I wrote above, there are some textbooks that measure matrix algorithms on n x n matrices using n to mean the single dimension and not the total size of the array.  In which case your original answer is correct.

Comment: Oh really? Thanks. I appreciate you looking into that and coming back to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being unable to find an example I will just construct an example.

log N usually implies a binary search. And there are plenty of N^2 algorithms.

Say you implement a bubble sort O(N^2), unfortunately you have to make a lookup of the sort values for each operation by using a binary search.

This is of course stupid, as you should memorize the values and not use bubble sort at all.